# Blank page when using Timber + Heroic Knowledge Base plugin

Tags: twig, timber

- PHP Version: 7.4.28
- MySQL: 8.0.29
- WordPress: 5.9.3
- Timber: 1.19.1

**I've installed Timber thru the backend upload page.**

I do have a custom theme using Timber / Twig - never had an issue before, with any other plugin.
Unfortunately when we use [Heroic Knowledge Base][1].

We do see those pages as totally clean/blank pages. **No code is generated in source.**

Seem like when I do comment in header.php

```
<?php

$GLOBALS['timberContext'] = Timber::get_context();
ob_start();
```

this line :

```
$GLOBALS['timberContext'] = Timber::get_context();
```

but then, unfortunately, timber is not loading templates obviously, but the content of Knowledgebase is displayed, but with no styling, header, footer etc, just plain plugin content.

*Is maybe anyone have a hint on how to fix this, investigate it?*

Comment: Did you already check the error_log?

Comment: Yes i have, nothing what would indicate this issue ....